# set data based on date excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook with two worksheets.

`Worksheet 1` is where all of the input occurs; `worksheet 2` simply copies the info based on specific criteria.

**Problem:** Worksheet 1 has a `today()` formula (it has to have it). Therefore, worksheet 2 resets everyday, with the input from that day. I need to set the info, even if the date changes on worksheet 1, so that worksheet 2 records the inputs from the past.

On Worksheet 1 I have cell `T1 = Today()`.
On Worksheet 2 I have Column A filled from `row 4` to `row 178`, with future dates from now until December 31st. Columns B to S, fill up according to inputs from worksheet 1 when T1 = cell.ColumnA on Worksheet 2.

How can I set the data on Worksheet 2, columns B to S, even if the date changes on Worksheet 1?

Comment: Hi Ana, I assume there is no historical data at all on Worksheet 1? If so is it a case of copying the data from worksheet 1 to worksheet 2 every day?

Comment: Hi maxhob17, correct. Although date on worksheet 1 may vary, worksheet 2 should record whatever happened before and record inputs when cell.ColumnA=T1 -> T1=Today().

Comment: Ok, quickest solution might be for you to record a macro. There's an overview of how to do it here: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Automate-tasks-with-the-Macro-Recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b let us know if you get stuck

Comment: So you want to copy your data from WS 1 into different rows in WS2 corresponding to the date from WS compared with column B in WS2?

Comment: Hi David - yes. But I want to keep the data already on WS2, even when the date one WS1 changes... want to keep an historic record, if you want to think of it that way. :)

Comment: Hi @maxhob17 it works to register new data on WS2, when altering the date on WS1, but it doesn't save the data input from previous dates...

Comment: @AnaBarros showing us both the sheets with sample data will help us to help you